# mdspan and the strict aliasing rule

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, strict-aliasing

If I’m not mistaken, accessing the second row onwards of a multidimensional array through pointer arithmetics is undefined behavior because of the strict aliasing rule.

There’s a proposal, called [`mdspan`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0009r5.html), which in my understanding is intended to provide a multidimensional array view. How such a class can be implemented without violating the strict aliasing rule?

A workaround might be `reinterpret_cast`ing the data to `char *` back and forth. However, I took a look to [this reference implementation](https://github.com/kokkos/array_ref/blob/master/reference/include/mdspan) and I didn’t see such a thing.

This is an excerpt from the reference implementation:

```
template < typename DataType , class ... Properties >
class mdspan
{
public:
  // ...
  using element_type = DataType ;
  using pointer      = element_type * ;
  using reference    = element_type & ;

private:
  pointer  m_ptr ;
  mapping  m_map ;

public:
  // ...

  template < class ... IndexType >
  explicit constexpr mdspan
    ( pointer ptr , IndexType ... DynamicExtents ) noexcept
    : m_ptr(ptr), m_map( DynamicExtents... ) {}


  // ...

  template< class ... IndexType >
  constexpr reference
  operator()( IndexType ... indices) const noexcept
    { return m_ptr[ m_map( indices... ) ]; }
};
```

Comment: Can you perhaps show us some code which you believe is UB? Seeing code tells us more than a thousand words.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In my understanding this class stores a pointer to the first element that, together with some template parameters defining the dimensions, allow accessing the elements by pointer arithmetics by computing the offsets, strides, etc., thus involving UB. I might be completely wrong though. The proposal is very terse example-wise.

Comment: @metalfox: "*How such a class can be implemented without violating the strict aliasing rule?*" It doesn't have to be. Standard library types don't have to be implementable outside of the standard library.

Comment: @NicolBolas I didn't know that. Maybe that's the answer to my question?

Comment: @NicolBolas, I believe that the fact the standard library is not implementable using core language rule is considered a defect of the language? Maybe this recent proposal to fix the language will make this mdspan implementable in C++: [P0593](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p0593r2.html)

Comment: @Oliv: One of the things that made C unique was that almost everything in the Standard library could be implemented within many implementations of the language (an ability called self-hosting), but since an implementation can be suitable for many purposes without being capable of self-hosting, the Standard does not require self-hosting ability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that I misunderstood the whole thing. The proposal clearly states that:

> The proposed polymorphic multidimensional array reference (`mdspan`) defines types and functions for mapping indices from a multidimensional index space (the domain) to members of a contiguous span of objects (the codomain).

Therefore it is designed to be a multidimensional view of a one-dimensional array, there being no aliasing issues.

I read elsewhere that it was intended to replace code like `f(double [][5],int)`, which was what confused me.

Comment: @einpoklum OK. There's a recent paper on this subject: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2554r0.html